# Issuing commands on remote linux

Tags: expect

I'm looking  for any way to do this task with expect:

```
Mac-mini:~ root# scp file peter@Mac-mini:file2
The authenticity of host 'mac-mini (192.168.1.105)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is b6:12:3e:48:10:e6:d2:1f:8f:57:f4:01:2d:f3:23:89.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?  yes
Password:  ********
```

and issue

```
crontab -l > crontab.src
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

set machine0 "Mac-minimini"
set machine1 "Mac-mini"
set machine2 "Mac-pro"
...
set machine19 "Mac-air"


for {set i 1} {$i < 20} {incr i 1} {
    eval spawn scp file peter@${machine${i}}:file2
    expect "connecting (yes/no)?"
    send "yes\r"
    #use correct prompt
    set prompt ":|#|\\\$"
    interact -o -nobuffer -re $prompt return
    send "password\r"
    interact -o -nobuffer -re $prompt return
    send "crontab -l > crontab.src\r"
    interact
}
```

Edit: You can use for loop and concatenate names for each machine using the variable of the loop.(e.g. Mac-mini0, Mac-mini1, ... Mac-mini19)

Edit2: I am not sure if ${machine${i}} works but worth to try..

Comment: Thanks ! I need do this task in 20 servers, how could I automate this task ?

Comment: @user1658549 See the post again please.

Comment: Ok, but where I put the server´s names ? and where I put the server´s password ? (It´s the same to all servers)

Comment: Ok, I´ll try this script on Monday...Thans a lot !

Comment: I´m getting this error: 
./alas: line 10: syntax error near unexpected token `i'
./alas: line 10: `for {set i 1} {$i < 20} {incr i 1} {'

Comment: You should add $ tag to the last i (incr $i 1). You can try the possibilities by removing or adding some characters like that. There might be syntax errors in the code.

Answer (score 0):

Set up an ssh key like so:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa
```

Place your public key on the remote machine (assuming you create a key in your home directory called id_rsa)

```
ssh-copy-id peter@Mac-mini
```

Then you will be able to scp without entering a password.

```
autoexpect -f scp file peter@Mac-mini:file2
```

For the crontab part, am assuming you mean on the remote machine.

```
autoexpect -f crontab ssh peter@Mac-mini "crontab -l > crontab.src"
```